# Срабатывает триггер, которого нет

Tags: sql, oracle, триггер

Может ли как-то сработать тригер, если его нет в БД?

Поясняю: есть триггер, который при добавлении данных (insert||update) в определённую таблицу активируется и записывает по своей логике определённые значения в поля таблицы. Есть система логирования, которая заявляет об успешной или неуспешной операции.
Так вот, выяснилось, что триггер не совсем корректно работает и нужно в нём изменить код немного.
Собственно код был написан и проверен, старый триггер отключён и переименован, а новый получил имя старого.
Теперь самое интересное. При проверке системы в любом случае срабатывает "старый" триггер, как показывают логи ошибки.

Что было испробовано:

- отключён старый триггер, включён новый
- переименован старый триггер
- удалён старый триггер и проверено, через (SELECT * FROM USER_OBJECTS
  WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TRIGGER';) отсутствие триггеров в бд с таким наименованием
- проверена вкладка triggers в изменяемой таблице (в oracle sql developer)
- почищен кэш бд
- ну и на крайняк проверено подключение, что работа идёт именно с этой базой данных..

Может ли триггер быть записан как-то в коде проекта? или какие могут быть ещё идеи, как заставить работать новый тригер поверх старого?  Просто ещё одна особенность в том, что когда я изменял текст ошибки в старом тригере, чтоб проверить, могу ли я его изменить - текст в логе так и не поменялся..

Если что, ошибки выходят такого формата (рисунок) т.е. там прям указывает какой тип ошибки, в какой строке. Следовательно работа всё-таки идёт с этой БД..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если срабатывает триггер которого нет, то значит триггер есть, либо вам кажется, что он срабатывает.

Comment: _может ли как-то сработать тригер, если его нет в БД_, нет, не может. В БД используются редакции? Сделайте минимальный воспроизводимый пример, гадать на кофейной гуще вряд ли у кого-то появится желание.

Comment: @0xdb редакций нет, используется ORA$BASE

Comment: Может срабатывает триггер из какой-то системной базы, если в вашей базе его нет. Ищите лучше.